# How to schedule a task every certain time interval in Xamarin IOs?

Tags: ios, xamarin, background, signalr

I have an application in Xamarin Forms of messaging through signalR.

The problem is that when the application falls asleep, the connection with signalR is lost and messages stop reaching the client.

I am investigating how I can from time to time check if the status of the connection with signalR is active and if it is not, make a reconnection.

This is my lines of code that would do the process.

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
{
   await MainViewModel.Instance.LobbyViewModel.ReConnectFromBackGround();
});
```

I've been through this documentation:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/backgrounding/ios-backgrounding-techniques/ios-backgrounding-with-tasks
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/backgrounding/ios-backgrounding-techniques/

In the case of Android I have not had problems but in IOs I do not know what approach I should take and how to do it.

Comment: You can't keep a network connection alive in an iOS app when it isn't active in the foreground. Push notifications should be used to deliver data to your app rather than relying on a persistent connection.

Comment: It is impossible to keep the signalr connection alive while in the background on iOS . In Android we can use  foreground service to achieve that , but for iOS especially in production mode apple does not allow app run in background just for connection .